# How to interpret a crashlog with no references to a specific class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, crash

Today my app crashed and generated this [crashlog](https://raw.github.com/gist/ea267200e2b6321af385/c21937cd1be4ceeaecb39d9b402ad4f71cd50b12/AppCrash.txt). The crashlog does not mention any classes in my project and to me it seems almost impossible to tackle this issue.

Any ideas how to approach this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Check this](http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/), it shows how to symbolicate crash logs

Comment: @DanielRHicks I checked the link again today and it seems to work again. I have added a summary of the steps [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565978/how-to-interpret-a-crashlog-with-no-references-to-a-specific-class/7648558#7648558)

Comment: My comment was about @ender's comment, and I was subsequently able to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tool included in Apple's Developer's tools called `symbolicatecrash`. With it you can symbolicate crash reports, but **note that you'll need the associated .dsym file of your build** Check [this post](http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/) to see a tutorial using it.

Comment: A little side note here: I am also using [testflight](http://testflightapp.com) and I figured out today that they let you upload the dSYM bundle as a zip to symbolise the crash-logs which are sent by testflight.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ran the symbolitecrash binary.

Find the binary `symbolitecrash`

```
locate symbolitecrash
```

Optional: You may add a convenience link to `/usr/bin`

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash
```

Copy the crash log to the `Debug-iphoneos` folder and go to the project

```
cp ~/Desktop/TheCrash.crash ~/Myproject/build/Debug-iphoneos
cd ~/MyProject/build/Debug-iphoneos
```

Run the crash log symbolicater

```
symbolicatecrash TheCrash.crash MyProject.app.dSYM > ReportWithSymbols.crash
```

#### The result

[crashlog http://k.minus.com/jk4X2obwZMI7j.png](http://k.minus.com/jk4X2obwZMI7j.png)