# iOS - App crash When I open the app from background (idle) mode for long time?

Tags: iphone, ios5, crash, mapkit

when I opened the app, let it run in background mode for long time, opened again and then it crashed again shortly after.The crash logs indicating that this crashed is caused by MapKit framework.It's only happen in device....

Can anyone make sense of this crash log?
Please Help me To solve out this problem 
Crash Log:-

```
 Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xe9cd5820
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x342fdfc2 0x342fa000 + 16322
    1   MapKit                          0x37c6daea 0x37c57000 + 92906
    2   MapKit                          0x37c6d688 0x37c57000 + 91784
    3   MapKit                          0x37c887d0 0x37c57000 + 202704
    4   MapKit                          0x37c842cc 0x37c57000 + 185036
    5   MapKit                          0x37c851b2 0x37c57000 + 188850
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x34012224 0x33ffa000 + 98852
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x3404eae2 0x33ffa000 + 346850
    8   MapKit                          0x37c7b066 0x37c57000 + 147558
    9   CoreLocation                    0x3089e5d8 0x30896000 + 34264
    10  CoreLocation                    0x3089df7a 0x30896000 + 32634
    11  CoreLocation                    0x30898638 0x30896000 + 9784
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x34087b2a 0x33ffa000 + 580394
    13  CoreFoundation                  0x34087158 0x33ffa000 + 577880
    14  CoreFoundation                  0x3408637a 0x33ffa000 + 574330
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x340094d6 0x33ffa000 + 62678
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x3400939e 0x33ffa000 + 62366
    17  GraphicsServices                0x3088dfc6 0x3088a000 + 16326
    18  UIKit                           0x3748a73c 0x37459000 + 202556
    19  HeyDenmark                      0x00002a54 main (main.m:14)
    20  HeyDenmark                      0x00002a0c 0x1000 + 6668

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe3b4 0x35fbd000 + 5044
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36ce8e78 0x36cdc000 + 52856
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36ce8b96 0x36cdc000 + 52118

    Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.locationd.registration.xpcq
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fce0a0 0x35fbd000 + 69792
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e4d42a 0x32e4a000 + 13354
    2   CoreLocation                    0x3089857e 0x30896000 + 9598
    3   CoreLocation                    0x3089ad2c 0x30896000 + 19756
    4   CoreLocation                    0x308ce19e 0x30896000 + 229790
    5   CoreLocation                    0x308cb97e 0x30896000 + 219518
    6   CoreLocation                    0x308cc78c 0x30896000 + 223116


    Thread 3 name:  WebThread
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe010 0x35fbd000 + 4112
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe206 0x35fbd000 + 4614
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x3408741c 0x33ffa000 + 578588
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x34086154 0x33ffa000 + 573780
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x340094d6 0x33ffa000 + 62678
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x3400939e 0x33ffa000 + 62366
    6   WebCore                         0x364dd128 0x36435000 + 688424
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59c16 0x32e4a000 + 64534
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59ad0 0x32e4a000 + 64208

    Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe010 0x35fbd000 + 4112
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe206 0x35fbd000 + 4614
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x3408741c 0x33ffa000 + 578588
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x34086154 0x33ffa000 + 573780
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x340094d6 0x33ffa000 + 62678

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fcecd4 0x35fbd000 + 72916
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5430a 0x32e4a000 + 41738
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5409c 0x32e4a000 + 41116

    Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fce570 0x35fbd000 + 71024
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x3408b66a 0x33ffa000 + 595562
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59c16 0x32e4a000 + 64534
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59ad0 0x32e4a000 + 64208

    Thread 7 name:  NetworkIO
    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe010 0x35fbd000 + 4112
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe206 0x35fbd000 + 4614
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x3408741c 0x33ffa000 + 578588
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x34086154 0x33ffa000 + 573780
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x340094d6 0x33ffa000 + 62678
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x3400939e 0x33ffa000 + 62366
    6   MapKit                          0x37c65412 0x37c57000 + 58386
    7   Foundation                      0x35a09a8a 0x359f9000 + 68234
    8   Foundation                      0x35a9d59a 0x359f9000 + 673178
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59c16 0x32e4a000 + 64534
    10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59ad0 0x32e4a000 + 64208

    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fcecd4 0x35fbd000 + 72916
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5430a 0x32e4a000 + 41738
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5409c 0x32e4a000 + 41116

    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fcecd4 0x35fbd000 + 72916
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5430a 0x32e4a000 + 41738
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5409c 0x32e4a000 + 41116

    Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fcecd4 0x35fbd000 + 72916
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5430a 0x32e4a000 + 41738
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e5409c 0x32e4a000 + 41116

    Thread 11:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe010 0x35fbd000 + 4112
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35fbe206 0x35fbd000 + 4614
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x3408741c 0x33ffa000 + 578588
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x34086154 0x33ffa000 + 573780
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x340094d6 0x33ffa000 + 62678
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x3400939e 0x33ffa000 + 62366
    6   CFNetwork                       0x3211be0c 0x320b6000 + 417292
    7   Foundation                      0x35a094b6 0x359f9000 + 66742
    8   Foundation                      0x35a9b41a 0x359f9000 + 664602
    9   Foundation                      0x35a996de 0x359f9000 + 657118
    10  HeyDenmark                      0x0000a2c4 -[TBXML initWithURL:] (TBXML.m:89)
    11  HeyDenmark                      0x00016820 -[HomePageViewController parseCityXML] (HomePageViewController.m:96)
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x34012224 0x33ffa000 + 98852
    13  HeyDenmark                      0x00008f7a -[MBProgressHUD launchExecution] (MBProgressHUD.m:422)
    14  Foundation                      0x35a09a8a 0x359f9000 + 68234
    15  Foundation                      0x35a9d59a 0x359f9000 + 673178
    16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59c16 0x32e4a000 + 64534
    17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e59ad0 0x32e4a000 + 64208

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
        r0: 0x001af040    r1: 0x358891aa      r2: 0x33a66755      r3: 0xe9cd5828
        r4: 0x00014000    r5: 0x001cf550      r6: 0x3fae9da0      r7: 0x2fdfeb50
        r8: 0x3faee904    r9: 0x0d62246a     r10: 0x3faee8dc     r11: 0x3faee8f8
        ip: 0x3fada604    sp: 0x2fdfeb34      lr: 0x37c6daf1      pc: 0x342fdfc2
      cpsr: 0x200f0030

    Binary Images:
        0x1000 -    0x40fff +HeyDenmark armv7  <c77a909c04a73ae9a3b6538aeef39c42> /var/mobile/Applications/B1016A54-FD50-4DFA-898B-A07C1B7F45D0/HeyDenmark.app/HeyDenmark
    0x2fe8e000 - 0x2feaffff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x30362000 - 0x30623fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x30624000 - 0x30661fff  IOKit armv7  <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x3066a000 - 0x30679fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
    0x30743000 - 0x3078cfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
    0x307e8000 - 0x307ecfff  FTClientServices armv7  <8f823e791c9e37b4b47323bb0286e86c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
    0x307ed000 - 0x3083efff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
    0x30842000 - 0x30849fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
    0x3088a000 - 0x30895fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x30896000 - 0x308e1fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
    0x308e4000 - 0x308eafff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
    0x308eb000 - 0x3094ffff  MessageUI armv7  <c9d526c181ed3625b32327044d78dad3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
    0x309af000 - 0x309b4fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x30cb0000 - 0x30cecfff  IMFoundation armv7  <d93ec1a0f854355da1e4f8aca176e749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
    0x30ced000 - 0x30d22fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
    0x30d23000 - 0x30dfdfff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
    0x30e5a000 - 0x30eb1fff  CoreAudio armv7  <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
    0x30eca000 - 0x31086fff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    0x3110c000 - 0x3112cfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x3116f000 - 0x3118efff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x31196000 - 0x311d9fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x311da000 - 0x31224fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
    0x315f3000 - 0x3173cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x3173f000 - 0x31743fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
    0x3179b000 - 0x317d8fff  FTServices armv7  <fc9e7d223d3f33898603cfba115f5094> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
    0x31817000 - 0x3181dfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x31836000 - 0x3186dfff  Security armv7  <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
    0x318ba000 - 0x31952fff  EventKit armv7  <f340aafa660d308a8cd86fd180aeaad9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
    0x31987000 - 0x31ae4fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
    0x31be2000 - 0x31be8fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
    0x31be9000 - 0x31d2efff  CoreGraphics armv7  <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
    0x31fb2000 - 0x31ffbfff  CoreMedia armv7  <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
    0x31ffc000 - 0x31ffffff  ActorKit armv7  <8c167170891238b3940f9f54105b6eb9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
    0x320b6000 - 0x3218dfff  CFNetwork armv7  <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    0x3218e000 - 0x3219ffff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
    0x3274e000 - 0x32751fff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
    0x32933000 - 0x329d9fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <d785fe33cd263f5aba861ad919c66924> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
    0x329dd000 - 0x32a06fff  AppleAccount armv7  <b0baa956f6a8308a8d9faac126ef6f95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
    0x32a25000 - 0x32a2dfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
    0x32b9a000 - 0x32d32fff  CoreData armv7  <dd6d139d99e5309f9df33f7b6a044b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
    0x32db0000 - 0x32db4fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x32e4a000 - 0x32ed7fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x32edb000 - 0x32edffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
    0x3312f000 - 0x3313efff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <09c637a85e3d3af488e59ced95a5a916> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
    0x3320d000 - 0x33211fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x332b7000 - 0x332fcfff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
    0x332fd000 - 0x33358fff  StoreServices armv7  <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
    0x33359000 - 0x3335afff  DataMigration armv7  <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
    0x33381000 - 0x334a5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
    0x334a9000 - 0x334aefff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c3062554536438f9874c88363df7f60b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
    0x334b1000 - 0x334b2fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x334c9000 - 0x334cafff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x334cb000 - 0x334d2fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
    0x334d3000 - 0x334d3fff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
    0x334d4000 - 0x334dbfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x33509000 - 0x3352cfff  MobileSync armv7  <be06df250fff368b92bc0a1defc6df9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
    0x33540000 - 0x33544fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
    0x33545000 - 0x335b5fff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
    0x336f3000 - 0x33756fff  IMCore armv7  <c235020b86123e95820f7323916023aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
    0x33757000 - 0x33758fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x33766000 - 0x33769fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x3376a000 - 0x337c0fff  GMM armv7  <5b18530ef2ab39fcb5f28da01beec3d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
    0x337c1000 - 0x337f4fff  MIME armv7  <0c29ae0826c53ebbaf9424b389016b68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
    0x33917000 - 0x33921fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
    0x33ab5000 - 0x33ab6fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x33ac3000 - 0x33b6ffff  MediaControlSender armv7  <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
    0x33c97000 - 0x33d45fff  Message armv7  <0d844e0108b1301bb08a74df3e3589b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
    0x33d46000 - 0x33d4afff  Marco armv7  <526949ce76323de09ee69812383c2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
    0x33d9f000 - 0x33dabfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x33db4000 - 0x33dd7fff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
    0x33e0f000 - 0x33e60fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x33e8d000 - 0x33eb2fff  OpenCL armv7  <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
    0x33ebe000 - 0x33ed4fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
    0x33ee2000 - 0x33eeefff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x33fd7000 - 0x33fdcfff  ApplePushService armv7  <2e620a6e8ee8387ba2771cfd7870c90e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
    0x33fdd000 - 0x33fe0fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x33ffa000 - 0x34111fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x34119000 - 0x3415dfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
    0x3415e000 - 0x3416bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x3418f000 - 0x3418ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x341a7000 - 0x341bcfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x342fa000 - 0x343c0fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x343eb000 - 0x343f0fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x343f1000 - 0x343f2fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x343f3000 - 0x3440cfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x344b1000 - 0x344c7fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
    0x344c8000 - 0x344ebfff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
    0x34617000 - 0x34b5bfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
    0x34b5c000 - 0x34b5efff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x34b9d000 - 0x34c8dfff  QuartzCore armv7  <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
    0x34c8e000 - 0x34c8ffff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
    0x34c90000 - 0x34d09fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
    0x34d44000 - 0x34e14fff  WebKit armv7  <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
    0x34e15000 - 0x3506ffff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ab91ec33f2b23606bd0443163beff710> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
    0x350e2000 - 0x350e6fff  CertUI armv7  <9d24f62513913888b2ac55f1db27b908> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
    0x351d3000 - 0x351dafff  MailServices armv7  <a5e048e513b237b78d62fb3996a85fa9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
    0x35222000 - 0x353fffff  AudioToolbox armv7  <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
    0x3541e000 - 0x35467fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x35578000 - 0x358e9fff  TextInput armv7  <64d1227219b03c51ba4854ec2f79c335> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
    0x359a0000 - 0x359b6fff  EAP8021X armv7  <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
    0x359b7000 - 0x359c2fff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
    0x359c3000 - 0x359f8fff  DataAccess armv7  <432578d415dd3398b3487f003b3100ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
    0x359f9000 - 0x35b77fff  Foundation armv7  <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x35b81000 - 0x35bcbfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
    0x35c88000 - 0x35c8efff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
    0x35cc5000 - 0x35cd4fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
    0x35cd5000 - 0x35d0efff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
    0x35d16000 - 0x35d19fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
    0x35d1f000 - 0x35d1ffff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
    0x35d50000 - 0x35d6dfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x35d76000 - 0x35d76fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
    0x35ed5000 - 0x35f14fff  QuickLook armv7  <fdc0e38e19f9316fb0923c390e8d3ccd> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
    0x35fbd000 - 0x35fd3fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x35fd4000 - 0x35fe0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
    0x35fe1000 - 0x36064fff  CoreMotion armv7  <f4365ff3974b3049b3f04b3f55a46ae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
    0x360c7000 - 0x360c9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
    0x3611b000 - 0x36147fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <f0eca72c10c537fa89b17fd97e003faf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
    0x36249000 - 0x36289fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
    0x3628a000 - 0x36334fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x36335000 - 0x36423fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x36435000 - 0x36becfff  WebCore armv7  <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
    0x36bed000 - 0x36c1dfff  ContentIndex armv7  <e610e7e8c8653d728dcc3c8fb471a994> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
    0x36c92000 - 0x36c92fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x36cad000 - 0x36cc1fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
    0x36cdc000 - 0x36cf2fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x36e9b000 - 0x36eb2fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <ca6cb19e568738a0a6e30b616ee33ab0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
    0x36f09000 - 0x36f44fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
    0x36f65000 - 0x36f65fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x36f66000 - 0x36faffff  AddressBook armv7  <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
    0x36fca000 - 0x36fcefff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
    0x37282000 - 0x37295fff  Notes armv7  <b2cb7346cb2b36eca53d22534c53b508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
    0x37296000 - 0x372a0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x372db000 - 0x372e1fff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
    0x373a1000 - 0x373aafff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x373ab000 - 0x37458fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x37459000 - 0x378f2fff  UIKit armv7  <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
    0x378f8000 - 0x37977fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x3799c000 - 0x379abfff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
    0x379ac000 - 0x379bdfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x379c6000 - 0x379c9fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x379ca000 - 0x37a06fff  AppSupport armv7  <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
    0x37a43000 - 0x37a43fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x37a58000 - 0x37b21fff  Celestial armv7  <c18e76311fc33016be930da83050b96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
    0x37c57000 - 0x37cd9fff  MapKit armv7  <1dd7d48dbbb6395ca77b97c2db4ae36e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
    0x37cdc000 - 0x37d18fff  iCalendar armv7  <59d80290d8733df8a6310da65b497fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
```

Comment: Please post a *symbolicated* crash log.

Comment: i paste symbolicated crash log

Comment: In a symbolicated crash log we wouldn't be seeing all those hex-numbers (0x33fba158 etc.) instead we would se the method names. Without that it is really hard to tell you what is happening from a crahslog. Please refer to a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565978/how-to-interpret-a-crashlog-with-no-references-to-a-specific-class or just google "symbolicate crash log Xcode 4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash report only contains symbols from your app, but not from the iOS. According to the binary symbols UDIDs it is 5.0.1.

Here is the symbolicated report, sadly MapKit calls don't resolve to anything useful.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xe9cd5820
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31516fc2 objc_msgSend + 22
1   MapKit                          0x37c6daea 0x37c57000 + 92906
2   MapKit                          0x37c6d688 0x37c57000 + 91784
3   MapKit                          0x37c887d0 0x37c57000 + 202704
4   MapKit                          0x37c842cc 0x37c57000 + 185036
5   MapKit                          0x37c851b2 0x37c57000 + 188850
6   CoreFoundation                  0x37995224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
7   CoreFoundation                  0x379d1ae2 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 154
8   MapKit                          0x37c7b066 0x37c57000 + 147558
9   CoreLocation                    0x3542a5d8 -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:] + 1164
10  CoreLocation                    0x35429f7a -[CLLocationManager onClientEvent:supportInfo:] + 194
11  CoreLocation                    0x35424638 __CLClientInvokeCallback_block_invoke_0 + 64
12  CoreFoundation                  0x37a0ab2a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 6
13  CoreFoundation                  0x37a0a158 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 152
14  CoreFoundation                  0x37a0937a __CFRunLoopRun + 1426
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3798c4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3798c39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
17  GraphicsServices                0x3750afc6 GSEventRunModal + 150
18  UIKit                           0x34e1c73c UIApplicationMain + 1084
19  HeyDenmark                      0x00002a54 main (main.m:14)
20  HeyDenmark                      0x00002a0c 0x1000 + 6668

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c03b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x376fde78 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x376fdb96 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.locationd.registration.xpcq
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332d00a0 __psynch_mutexdrop + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5242a pthread_mutex_unlock + 250
2   CoreLocation                    0x3542457e CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent, __CFDictionary const*) + 306
3   CoreLocation                    0x35426d2c ___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0 + 320
4   CoreLocation                    0x3545a19e __setDefaultMessageHandler_onQueue_block_invoke_0 + 46
5   CoreLocation                    0x3545797e CLConnection::handleMessage(CLConnectionMessage*) + 42
6   CoreLocation                    0x3545878c __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 360


Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37a0a41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37a09154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x3225d128 RunWebThread(void*) + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ec16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ead0 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37a0a41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37a09154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5930a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5909c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332d0570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x37a0e66a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ec16 _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ead0 thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  NetworkIO
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37a0a41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37a09154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   MapKit                          0x37bf3412 MKTileSupportsTileSetStyle + 4850
7   Foundation                      0x318dca8a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3197059a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ec16 _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ead0 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5930a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5909c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5930a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5909c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332d0cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5930a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5909c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332c0206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37a0a41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37a09154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3798c39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   CFNetwork                       0x36f6de0c CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 340
7   Foundation                      0x318dc4b6 +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 242
8   Foundation                      0x3196e41a -[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:] + 206
9   Foundation                      0x3196c6de +[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:] + 46
10  HeyDenmark                      0x0000a2c4 -[TBXML initWithURL:] (TBXML.m:89)
11  HeyDenmark                      0x00016820 -[HomePageViewController parseCityXML] (HomePageViewController.m:96)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x37995224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
13  HeyDenmark                      0x00008f7a -[MBProgressHUD launchExecution] (MBProgressHUD.m:422)
14  Foundation                      0x318dca8a -[NSThread main] + 66
15  Foundation                      0x3197059a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ec16 _pthread_start + 314
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e5ead0 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001af040    r1: 0x358891aa      r2: 0x33a66755      r3: 0xe9cd5828
    r4: 0x00014000    r5: 0x001cf550      r6: 0x3fae9da0      r7: 0x2fdfeb50
    r8: 0x3faee904    r9: 0x0d62246a     r10: 0x3faee8dc     r11: 0x3faee8f8
    ip: 0x3fada604    sp: 0x2fdfeb34      lr: 0x37c6daf1      pc: 0x342fdfc2
  cpsr: 0x200f0030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x40fff +HeyDenmark armv7  <c77a909c04a73ae9a3b6538aeef39c42> /var/mobile/Applications/B1016A54-FD50-4DFA-898B-A07C1B7F45D0/HeyDenmark.app/HeyDenmark
0x2fe8e000 - 0x2feaffff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30362000 - 0x30623fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x30624000 - 0x30661fff  IOKit armv7  <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3066a000 - 0x30679fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30743000 - 0x3078cfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x307e8000 - 0x307ecfff  FTClientServices armv7  <8f823e791c9e37b4b47323bb0286e86c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x307ed000 - 0x3083efff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30842000 - 0x30849fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3088a000 - 0x30895fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30896000 - 0x308e1fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x308e4000 - 0x308eafff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x308eb000 - 0x3094ffff  MessageUI armv7  <c9d526c181ed3625b32327044d78dad3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x309af000 - 0x309b4fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x30cb0000 - 0x30cecfff  IMFoundation armv7  <d93ec1a0f854355da1e4f8aca176e749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x30ced000 - 0x30d22fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30d23000 - 0x30dfdfff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30e5a000 - 0x30eb1fff  CoreAudio armv7  <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30eca000 - 0x31086fff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3110c000 - 0x3112cfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3116f000 - 0x3118efff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31196000 - 0x311d9fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x311da000 - 0x31224fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x315f3000 - 0x3173cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3173f000 - 0x31743fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3179b000 - 0x317d8fff  FTServices armv7  <fc9e7d223d3f33898603cfba115f5094> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x31817000 - 0x3181dfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31836000 - 0x3186dfff  Security armv7  <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x318ba000 - 0x31952fff  EventKit armv7  <f340aafa660d308a8cd86fd180aeaad9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31987000 - 0x31ae4fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x31be2000 - 0x31be8fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31be9000 - 0x31d2efff  CoreGraphics armv7  <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31fb2000 - 0x31ffbfff  CoreMedia armv7  <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31ffc000 - 0x31ffffff  ActorKit armv7  <8c167170891238b3940f9f54105b6eb9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x320b6000 - 0x3218dfff  CFNetwork armv7  <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3218e000 - 0x3219ffff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3274e000 - 0x32751fff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32933000 - 0x329d9fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <d785fe33cd263f5aba861ad919c66924> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x329dd000 - 0x32a06fff  AppleAccount armv7  <b0baa956f6a8308a8d9faac126ef6f95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x32a25000 - 0x32a2dfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x32b9a000 - 0x32d32fff  CoreData armv7  <dd6d139d99e5309f9df33f7b6a044b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32db0000 - 0x32db4fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32e4a000 - 0x32ed7fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32edb000 - 0x32edffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3312f000 - 0x3313efff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <09c637a85e3d3af488e59ced95a5a916> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x3320d000 - 0x33211fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x332b7000 - 0x332fcfff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x332fd000 - 0x33358fff  StoreServices armv7  <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33359000 - 0x3335afff  DataMigration armv7  <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x33381000 - 0x334a5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x334a9000 - 0x334aefff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c3062554536438f9874c88363df7f60b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x334b1000 - 0x334b2fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x334c9000 - 0x334cafff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x334cb000 - 0x334d2fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x334d3000 - 0x334d3fff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x334d4000 - 0x334dbfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33509000 - 0x3352cfff  MobileSync armv7  <be06df250fff368b92bc0a1defc6df9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x33540000 - 0x33544fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33545000 - 0x335b5fff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x336f3000 - 0x33756fff  IMCore armv7  <c235020b86123e95820f7323916023aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x33757000 - 0x33758fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33766000 - 0x33769fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3376a000 - 0x337c0fff  GMM armv7  <5b18530ef2ab39fcb5f28da01beec3d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x337c1000 - 0x337f4fff  MIME armv7  <0c29ae0826c53ebbaf9424b389016b68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x33917000 - 0x33921fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33ab5000 - 0x33ab6fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x33ac3000 - 0x33b6ffff  MediaControlSender armv7  <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x33c97000 - 0x33d45fff  Message armv7  <0d844e0108b1301bb08a74df3e3589b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x33d46000 - 0x33d4afff  Marco armv7  <526949ce76323de09ee69812383c2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x33d9f000 - 0x33dabfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x33db4000 - 0x33dd7fff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x33e0f000 - 0x33e60fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33e8d000 - 0x33eb2fff  OpenCL armv7  <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x33ebe000 - 0x33ed4fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x33ee2000 - 0x33eeefff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x33fd7000 - 0x33fdcfff  ApplePushService armv7  <2e620a6e8ee8387ba2771cfd7870c90e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33fdd000 - 0x33fe0fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x33ffa000 - 0x34111fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x34119000 - 0x3415dfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3415e000 - 0x3416bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3418f000 - 0x3418ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x341a7000 - 0x341bcfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x342fa000 - 0x343c0fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x343eb000 - 0x343f0fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x343f1000 - 0x343f2fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x343f3000 - 0x3440cfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x344b1000 - 0x344c7fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x344c8000 - 0x344ebfff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x34617000 - 0x34b5bfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34b5c000 - 0x34b5efff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x34b9d000 - 0x34c8dfff  QuartzCore armv7  <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34c8e000 - 0x34c8ffff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34c90000 - 0x34d09fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34d44000 - 0x34e14fff  WebKit armv7  <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34e15000 - 0x3506ffff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ab91ec33f2b23606bd0443163beff710> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x350e2000 - 0x350e6fff  CertUI armv7  <9d24f62513913888b2ac55f1db27b908> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x351d3000 - 0x351dafff  MailServices armv7  <a5e048e513b237b78d62fb3996a85fa9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x35222000 - 0x353fffff  AudioToolbox armv7  <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3541e000 - 0x35467fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35578000 - 0x358e9fff  TextInput armv7  <64d1227219b03c51ba4854ec2f79c335> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x359a0000 - 0x359b6fff  EAP8021X armv7  <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x359b7000 - 0x359c2fff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x359c3000 - 0x359f8fff  DataAccess armv7  <432578d415dd3398b3487f003b3100ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x359f9000 - 0x35b77fff  Foundation armv7  <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35b81000 - 0x35bcbfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35c88000 - 0x35c8efff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x35cc5000 - 0x35cd4fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35cd5000 - 0x35d0efff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35d16000 - 0x35d19fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35d1f000 - 0x35d1ffff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35d50000 - 0x35d6dfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35d76000 - 0x35d76fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x35ed5000 - 0x35f14fff  QuickLook armv7  <fdc0e38e19f9316fb0923c390e8d3ccd> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35fbd000 - 0x35fd3fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35fd4000 - 0x35fe0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35fe1000 - 0x36064fff  CoreMotion armv7  <f4365ff3974b3049b3f04b3f55a46ae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x360c7000 - 0x360c9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3611b000 - 0x36147fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <f0eca72c10c537fa89b17fd97e003faf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x36249000 - 0x36289fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3628a000 - 0x36334fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x36335000 - 0x36423fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x36435000 - 0x36becfff  WebCore armv7  <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36bed000 - 0x36c1dfff  ContentIndex armv7  <e610e7e8c8653d728dcc3c8fb471a994> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x36c92000 - 0x36c92fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x36cad000 - 0x36cc1fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36cdc000 - 0x36cf2fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36e9b000 - 0x36eb2fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <ca6cb19e568738a0a6e30b616ee33ab0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36f09000 - 0x36f44fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36f65000 - 0x36f65fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x36f66000 - 0x36faffff  AddressBook armv7  <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x36fca000 - 0x36fcefff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x37282000 - 0x37295fff  Notes armv7  <b2cb7346cb2b36eca53d22534c53b508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x37296000 - 0x372a0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x372db000 - 0x372e1fff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x373a1000 - 0x373aafff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x373ab000 - 0x37458fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x37459000 - 0x378f2fff  UIKit armv7  <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x378f8000 - 0x37977fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3799c000 - 0x379abfff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x379ac000 - 0x379bdfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x379c6000 - 0x379c9fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x379ca000 - 0x37a06fff  AppSupport armv7  <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37a43000 - 0x37a43fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x37a58000 - 0x37b21fff  Celestial armv7  <c18e76311fc33016be930da83050b96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x37c57000 - 0x37cd9fff  MapKit armv7  <1dd7d48dbbb6395ca77b97c2db4ae36e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x37cdc000 - 0x37d18fff  iCalendar armv7  <59d80290d8733df8a6310da65b497fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
```

The top call to `libobjc` in the crashing thread symbolicates to `objc_msgSend + 22` which indicates that MapKit is trying to send a message to a deallocated object. Please make sure that the MapKit delegate is set to nil when dismissing the view.

Are you showing the current users location on the map? Since the call seems to be triggered by the CLLocationManager on a new event, which could be a new position is detected.

This should give you a good start now.

Comment: how you are symbolicating the crash logs from elppa? how you are getting these lines - 6   CoreFoundation                  0x37995224 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 36
7   CoreFoundation                  0x379d1ae2 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 154

Comment: In this particular scenario I am using the HockeyApp.net infrastructure, which I am a developer of. We developed our own symbolication process for that hosted service. In general you should be able to use the symbolicatecrash.pl script that is part of Xcode, all you should need to do is add an valid header to the report. The posted crash report is missing that, but any iOS 5.0.1 report header will do it.